# Node streams: how to transform a Buffer stream to write arrays to the output

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I have a readableStream which contains buffer data (audio samples).
In my custom transform I read the bytes and separate out the audio buffer into separate channels (L/R).

I'd like the next stream consumer to receive these transformed arrays to do further manipulations.
When I try to do so, it throws an error: `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received an instance of Array`

I thought the `readableObjectMode` & `writableObjectMode` would help, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Any idea how I solve this?

```js
// Setup the transform
const extractChannels = new ExtractChannelsTransform(
  this.sampleFormat
)

this.stream
  .pipe(extractChannels)
  .pipe(process.stdout)


// ExtractChannelsTransform class
class ExtractChannelsTransform extends Transform {

  constructor(sampleFormat) {
    super({
      objectMode: true,
      readableObjectMode: false,
      writableObjectMode: true
    })
  }

  _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {

    const channels = ... // chunk bytes are read here and transformed into an array per channel

    callback(null, channels)
  }

}
```

Comment: Where in the pipeline are the arrays created? Is it selectedChannels that shall receive the arrays? If so, I believe the readableObjectMode should be “true”.

Comment: I've updated the code snippet. Those parameters were used to read out the raw bytes from the audiobuffer and are not important. The arrays are created on the line with the comment `chunk bytes are read here an...`. Over there I read the buffer bytes, parse them and convert that buffer into an array of channels.

Comment: I gather that `this.stream` produces buffer data and that ExtractChannelsTransform shall transform these buffers to arrays. Given the example above, you should flip the value of `readableObjectMode`. If that doesn't solve the issue, you should provide a minimal running example.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the output chunks (channels) into string or buffer regarding the error message.

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream

> All streams created by Node.js APIs operate exclusively on strings and Buffer (or Uint8Array) objects.